# Dialog injecting a service

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers. One which handles the opening of a dialog and one which is the controller for the dialog itself.

Both controllers inject a service 'Directory', however on the dialog controller, the service is `undefined`.

**Dialog Controller:**

```
window.angular.module('tmo.controllers.directory', [])
    .controller('DirectoryController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'Directory',
        function ($scope, Global, number, Directory) {
            $scope.global = Global;
            $scope.direct = function (number) {
                Directory.direct(number);
            };
}]);
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'direct' of undefined
```

When I use the same method from the main controller (not the dialog), the Directory service is not undefined.

Comment: check your inline annotation it has to match the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument names of the controller are

```
'$scope', 'Global', 'Directory'
```

But the argument values are

```
$scope, Global, number, Directory
```

So the `number` argument actually contains the Directory, and the `Directory` argument is undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will accept the answer once SO lets me!